# Closed range operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear operator between two normed spaces. I'm trying to show that an operator $T$ has closed range if and only if $\operatorname{im}(T) = (\ker{(T^*)})^{\perp}$.

Is there a way to do it without the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry; no - between arbitrary normed spaces. Does it carry over to Hilbert spaces? What about Banach?

Comment: is your $T$ bounded, I know the theorem with bounded operator. And I think you should add $\overline{Im(A)}$ instead of only $Im(A)$

Comment: No; It is easy to show that ${im(T)}^{\perp} = ( \ker{T^*} )$ for linear operators $T$. Indeed $T^*x = 0 \; \Longleftrightarrow \; \langle T^*x,y\rangle = 0 \; \Longleftrightarrow \; \langle x, Ty \rangle = 0 \; \Longleftrightarrow \; x \perp im(T)$.

Comment: How would you show it for bounded operators? - the version in the question that is. I'm pretty sure it holds for unbounded too.

Comment: suppose $T:X\rightarrow Y$, If $U=Im(A)$, then $\overline{U}\subset (U^{\perp})^{\perp}$, define $P:Y\rightarrow \overline{U}$, as orthogonal projection map, then for any $x\in (U^{\perp})^{\perp}$, $Px-x\perp U$, but we also have $Px-x\perp U^{\perp}$, since $\overline{U}\subset (U^{\perp})^{\perp}$. Thus $x=Px$ in $\overline{U}$, thus $\overline{U} = (U^{\perp})^{\perp}$

Comment: @julien: For a set $A \subset Y^*$, it's not unreasonable to *define* $A^\perp := \{y \in Y : f(y) = 0 \,\forall f \in A\}$.

Answer (score 2):

The first step should be to clarify what the orthogonal notation means.

Let $Y$ be normed vector space,  and let $Y^*$ denote its topological dual.
If $F$ is a subset of  $Y$, then we denote
$$
F^\perp:=\{\phi\in Y^*\;;\;\phi(y)=0\;\forall y\in F\}.
$$
This is a weak* closed subspace of $Y^*$.

Now if $G$ is a subset of $Y^*$, we denote
$$
G^0:=\{y\in Y\;;\;\phi(y)=0\;\forall \phi\in G\}.
$$
This is a normed closed subspace of $Y$. Note that it is not $G^\perp$, which is  a weak* closed subspace of the bidual $Y^{**}$.

**Claim:** For every subspace $F$ of $Y$, we have $(F^\perp)^0=\overline{F}$, the norm closure of $F$.

**Proof:** It is trivial to see that $F\subseteq (F^\perp)^0$. Since the latter is norm closed, we get $\overline{F}\subseteq (F^\perp)^0$. Now if $y$ does not belong to $\overline{F}$, Hahn-Banach gives us $\phi\in F^\perp$ such that $\phi(y)\neq 0$. So $y$ does not lie in $(F^\perp)^0$. This proves the reverse inclusion. QED.

**Your question:** Let $T:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a bounded linear operator between two normed vector spaces. As you observed, it is straghtforward to show that
$$
\mbox{Ker} T^*=(\mbox{Im} T)^\perp
$$
in $Y^*$. Therefore
$$
(\mbox{Ker} T^*)^0=((\mbox{Im} T)^\perp)^0=\overline{\mbox{Im} T}.
$$
Now clearly $T$ has closed range if and only if $(\mbox{Ker} T^*)^0=\mbox{Im} T$.

**Note:** I really can't see how we could avoid Hahn-Banach in the proof of the claim.